# Allowing others to connect their Facebook Page to our App

Tags: facebook

I created a Facebook app that has a webhook for Facebook Page messages through FB Messenger. Essentially the purpose is to add a bot to our Facebook Pages. We now want to start creating Messenger bots for other business' pages.

Facebook allows us to have our app webhook subscribe to our own FB Pages, but we can't find any way to add another business' FB Page (screenshot below)

[image]

How can we make it so that our app can be installed by other businesses to their FB Pages? (so that the bot will work for their pages). 
We put our app through the app review process and it was approved, but I only put in my personal information, not the business' information. Could this be a blocker?

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe pages to / unsubscribe them from your webhook via the [`page/subscribed_apps`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/subscribed_apps/) API endpoint.

You need to have a page admin login to your app and grant it permission to manage their pages, then you get a page access token, and with that you make the request to subscribe the page to your webhook.